# How to remove the stretchable property from Multiline Textbox?

Tags: asp.net

I have a Multiline Textbox.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="tx" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
```

How to remove the stretchable property from Multiline Textbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it through CSS as:

```
textarea {
resize: none;
}
```